# Limiting Apache Camel memory consumption

Tags: glassfish, jms, apache-camel

we're using apache camel to read files from a directory and putting the content into a JMS Topic inside a Glassfish 4.1 server. Other software parts are reading from this JMS Topic and processing the content.

We're now having the problem, that the server runs for a time with an acceptable load, but after some hours the memory consumption is increasing and the Server starts swapping. At that point is the server out of control.

Can anybody give me a hint wich skrews (JMS ConnectionFactory, ThreadPools etc.) I have to turn?

Comment: what JMS broker are you using?  is it embedded in your Camel app or standlone?

Comment: It sould be OpenJms running provided by the glassfish server

Comment: hmmm...not familiar with OpenJMS, but in AMQ there are limits to memory to buffer messages per destination, etc...that would limit this.

Comment: We're set the imq.system.max_size property to 10m and reduced the max connection limit to 20 conntections. After that change we hadn't any propblems with the memory.

Answer (score 0):

your JMS broker should have a way to configure the max memory/message count to buffer in memory for a given destination, etc...ActiveMQ lets you [configure this](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html) easily...might try something similar.

also, if you are dealing with large files that you are parsing (splitting, etc)...you might try enabling the streaming mode as this is a a general best practice to address memory usage...

otherwise, I see a heap dump in your future to analyze what exactly is eating up memory...

Comment: We have very small files of 20kb - but we're getting 10 of them each second. So If we have a small downtime - camel loads all of them into the memory, ignoring the processing speed. But I will try the streaming mode.